# Git for Mac OS X 10.4

Tags: git, version-control

Where should I download a free Git client for Mac OS X 10.4 (Tiger)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it looks like the [pre-compiled version](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3) on Mac OS X are compiled for Leopard or later, you will probably have to compile it yourself, though you could download those and see if they work. You could download the [source](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.7.3.tar.bz2) and compile it yourself, or you could [install MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php) and then run `sudo port install git-core`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to install Homebrew - http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Then:

```
$ brew install git
==> Downloading http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.6.5.7.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.6.5.7
==> make install
==> Downloading http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-manpages-1.6.5.7.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.6.5.7: 383 files, 16M, built in 74 seconds
```

All detailed here:

http://help.github.com/mac-git-installation/

Answer (score 0):

By client, I assume you mean the GUI frontend for git, in which case I recommend [gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/). It's quite nice for visualizations.

If you mean the command line tool, git, I recommend downloading from source (unless you have a profound need for a package manager). That requires you to download XCode, which installs a bunch command line tools needed to build from scratch. Just download git's source on the home page, `cd` in to the directory and:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and you're done!

Comment: Are you sure you need XCode? Installing an IDE to use GCC seems a little obserd. However, I've never used Mac so I don't know if theres a better away.

Comment: Well, if you look at other solutions, like Homebrew, it requires XCode too. So, I'd just go ahead and install it. For **any** kind of development on a Mac, XCode is a must (not only for the tools).